# In Security Essentials, how do I enable scanning of files previously restored from quarantine?

Tags: anti-virus, ms-security-essentials, quarantine

I had infected .htm files on a web server.  I wanted to see the text of one of the files, so I could see the malicious code myself.  However, whenever I would download one of the .htm files to my computer via FTP, Microsoft Security Essentials would scan and quarantine the file for "Exploit:HTML/IframeRef.EX".  So I went to the History tab in Security Essentials and restored the one of the files from quarantine.  I opened it up in a text editor, and saw the iframe call to a spammy PHP script.

I deleted the file from my computer, but now when I download the same file again, Security Essentials ignores the file and leaves it on my computer unscanned.  Security Essentials will scan and quarantine other files, but not the one I restored from quarantine.

How do I get Security Essentials to start scanning that filename again?

The file no longer shows in my History, "Quarantined items" list.  It also doesn't show up in my "Allowed items" list.  It does appear in the "All detected items" list, but the only option there is to "Allow item".  There is a button labelled "Remove all" on the "All detected items" list, but the tooltip says that it will "Delete all previously detected items from the history," which is not really what I want to do.